# Printing out a string in Perl and getting weird result

Tags: arrays, string, perl, printing

I am trying to print out a concatenated string in Perl, but I'm getting a weird result.  Here is a bit of my code, I am getting a string and taking out a part of it and putting it into an array, @array.  I'm then trying to take pieces of that array and concatenate them into a string.

```
@input = [];
while ( $in = <STDIN> ) { 
    print "# got $in";
    chomp $in;
    @inS = split(/ /, $in);
    if ($inS[2] ne ".pau"){
        print "$inS[2]";
        push(@input, $inS[2]);
    }
}

$inputSize = @input;
$stringN = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $inputSize; $i++) {
    $stringN .= $input[$i];
    print "$stringN\n";
}
```

But the result I get from printing gets this big number attached onto the front.  Here is an example.  Instead of getting just "faIv", I get:

```
 ARRAY(0x500f450)faIv
```

It seems like it thinks my string is an array?  Is that because of concatenating with an array element?  Any assistance would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: What's in @input? I can replicate the output if I set `@input = ( [] . 'faIv' );`

Comment: `ARRAY(0x500f450)` is a stringified representation of an Array Reference.  You'll want to take a closer look at how you define `@input`.

Comment: Updated to show how I am creating    @input

Comment: should be `my @input = ();` not `@input = [];`

Answer (score 4):

`[]` is a *reference* to an array. `@input = [];` creates an array named `@input` and puts a reference to an empty array as the first element of `@input`. If you want to initialize `@input` to an empty array, use `@input = ();`.